# FileIterator in Java?

Tags: java, filesystems, traversal

Do you know where I can find a library that implements **FileIterator** (or something similar) in Java? Would be nice to have it working like the following (unchecked code):

```
Iterator it = new FileIterator();
it.addDirectory("../some-dir/");
it.addInclude("**/*.java");
it.addExclude(".svn/**");
while (it.hasNext()) {
  File f = it.next();
  System.out.println("File found: " + f);
}
```

Something similar is implemented in [Maven FileSet](http://maven.apache.org/shared/file-management/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/model/fileset/FileSet.html), but I don't think it's a good idea to add Maven JAR to my project :)

Comment: You want a library, but you don't want to add a JAR?

Comment: he meant he doesn't want to add maven jar that contains FileSet class

Comment: @BalusC Well, I just think that Maven JAR is an overkill for just one small class :)

Comment: There's actually some ambiguity. Are you looking for a standard Java SE provided solution? The `java.io.FileFilter` is the closest you can get. You could wrap it in a small class with help of builder/fluent pattern.

Comment: @BalusC Exactly, `FileFilter` is one of the classes to be used in `FileSet`/`FileIterator` I'm looking for. I just don't want to reinvent a wheel, since the task is very common, I suppose..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
 Iterator<File> iterateFiles(File directory,
                                          String[] extensions,
                                          boolean recursive)
```

Comment: `iterateFiles(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter, IOFileFilter dirFilter)` should be exactly what is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DirectoryWalker in Commons-IO, here is example:

```
public class FileCleaner extends DirectoryWalker {

    public FileCleaner() {
      super();
    }

    public List clean(File startDirectory) {
      List results = new ArrayList();
      walk(startDirectory, results);
      return results;
    }

    protected boolean handleDirectory(File directory, int depth, Collection results) {
      // delete svn directories and then skip
      if (".svn".equals(directory.getName())) {
        directory.delete();
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }

    }

    protected void handleFile(File file, int depth, Collection results) {
      // delete file and add to list of deleted
      file.delete();
      results.add(file);
    }
  }
```

Other examples can be found at  http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html